# How to customize a webpack plugin to modify 'loadingEnded' in the runtime?

Tags: webpack-5

I want to modify the 'JsonpChunkLoadingRuntimeModule' used in 'JsonpChunkLoadingPlugin' by replacing the 'loadingEnded' function with a new one. However, when I bind my custom plugin using 'compilation.hooks.additionalTreeRuntimeRequirements' to test feasibility, I encounter an error during the build. The error message is as follows:

```
node_modules/.pnpm/webpack@5.89.0_webpack-cli@5.1.4/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3543
                this._modules.set(module.identifier(), module);
                                         ^

TypeError: module.identifier is not a function
    at Compilation.addRuntimeModule
```

the custom plugin is as follows:

```
const Template = require("webpack").Template;

class MyPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap("MyPlugin", (compilation) => {
      compilation.hooks.additionalTreeRuntimeRequirements.tap(
        "MyPlugin",
        (chunk, set) => {
          if (chunk.hasRuntime()) {
            const runtimeModule = new MyRuntimeModule(/* options */);
            compilation.addRuntimeModule(chunk, runtimeModule);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }
}

class MyRuntimeModule {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options || {};
  }

  generate() {
    // test add code
    return Template.asString(['console.log("My Runtime Module");']);
  }
}

module.exports = MyPlugin;
```